# Problem with K2 Plugins - Joomla - Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, k2

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /home/......./archi/html/com_k2/templates/default/item.php on line 398

```
 396 <!-- K2 Plugins: K2BeforeDisplayContent -->
 397 <?php echo $this->item->event->K2BeforeDisplayContent; ?>
 398 <?php if($this->item->params->get('itemExtraFields') && count($this->item->extra_fields)): ?>
```

Тhis error appears in the blog part and in particular by entering the separate stratum. Not in the general review, but in the specific article.

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please take our [tour].  Please `var_dump($this->item->extra_fields)` to show what is not countable.

Comment: This is the file code. https://github.com/Dmtrv91/siteProblem/blob/main/Problem%20with%20K2%20Plugins%20-%20Joomla%20-%20Warning:%20count():%20Parameter%20must%20be%20an%20array

Comment: We need to know what value is held in the variable causing trouble.  It _should_ be an array, but it is not.  If it is _falsey_, then `!empty()` will suffice, but if it has some random string in it, then that is another problem.  We need more diagnostic details or we are just assuming/guessing at resolutions. Call `var_dump()` before the error and then `exit()`.  I am likely to recommend `if($this->item->params->get('itemExtraFields') && !empty($this->item->extra_fields)):` but I need more clarity before I do.

Comment: The warning is coming from the `count()` method of PHP in the code in line 398. If `count()` method is used it can only be used with an array or a countable object, otherwise an E_WARNING will be emitted since PHP7.2: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration72.incompatible.php

Comment: I hope @Lodder will extend his answer on this too...

Answer (score 1):

Since the value of `$this->item->extra_fields` is either an array or `null`, you don't need to check if it "is set" with `!empty()` or `isset()`; a truthy value check is all that is required.

```
if ($this->item->params->get('itemExtraFields') && $this->item->extra_fields) {
```

By writing `$this->item->extra_fields` (without any function calls or operators) into the conditional expression, it is checked for "truthiness" or in other words checking its boolean value.

- `null` has a boolean value of `false`.
- an empty array has a boolean value of `false`.
- a non-empty array has a boolean value of `true`.

Here is [a quick demonstration](https://3v4l.org/WLRk5).

So, if the `extra_fields` property is not null and not an empty array, then it will pass the conditional criteria and enter that branch of the condition block.

If there is any possibility that `$this->item->extra_fields` might not be set, then the safer technique is to call `!empty()` on it.  Using `!empty()` for ALL falsey checks in a project will lead to loads of unnecessary code bloat.  If you are assured that a variable will be declared/set, then don't make the function call.  (Objects are a different matter and cannot be treated the same way, but I will not digress.)

Answer (score 0):

`$this->item->extra_fields` is most likely empty/null and therefore not an array or object, so PHP cannot `count` it.

I believe you can add an additional check to see if it's empty and set, like so:

```
<?php if (!empty($this->item->extra_fields) && isset($this->item->extra_fields)) : ?>
    <?php if ($this->item->params->get('itemExtraFields') && count($this->item->extra_fields)) : ?>
        // Do something
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Probably in this case it is better to pre-check whether the `$var` is countable too with using `is_countable($var)` method.

Comment: It is *never* necessary to write both checks (`isset()` and `!empty()`) in a condition: `!empty($this->item->extra_fields) && isset($this->item->extra_fields)`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4559976/2943403 If `!empty($this->item->extra_fields)` is satisfied, then `isset($this->item->extra_fields)` will **always** be satisfied.  If a variable is declared/set (and there is evidence that it is because there is no warning of accessing an undeclared property), then checking an array for non-emptiness is as simple as `if ($this->item->extra_fields) {`

Comment: `It is never necessary to write both checks`. That's completely incorrect. They are two different methods, performing two different tasks. So yes, you **can** use them in the same condition if you need to. `!empty()` will reject `0`, which is a completely valid value.

Comment: You're both welcome to write additional answers

Comment: @mickmackusa - I thought that you will notice that (you did it few times earlier at other posts and I agree with you mostly on that) however as @Lodder mentioned there are few cases where we should use both checks together, like when you have an empty string for example: `””` the variable is set. So the `isset()` is satisfied (because the value is not null) but the `!empty()` condition is not satisfied. So there can be few exceptions from the “never”...

Comment: @Lodder - please do not take these comments personal, your answer is the most optimal approach on this question. But the question itself is so invaluable (sorry to say that) that it does not worth to write more answers on this, since these warning should not be seen on production sites at all in the first place as error reporting should be turned off to not show these PHP warnings... and the K2 developers should refine these codes as you did in your answer...

Comment: There is a misunderstanding in what I am trying to explain. If you want 0, don't use empty().  If you are going to use `!empty()` then there is absolutely 100% no reason to also call `isset()`. I am not telling any fibs here.  If you aren't calling `!empty()`, then `isset()` can certainly be useful.  If you don't believe me, read the previously posted Stack Overflow link -- it spells it all out.  Truth: `!empty()` is enough for this task.  There is no convincing me otherwise, because this is a provable fact.  I cannot accurately answer until the value of the variable is posted in the question.

Comment: @mickmackusa - It depends on the data being returned. I don't know if `extra_fields` is only an object property if it has data, or whether it's set to `null`, or whether it's set to `0`, so I've added the additional `isset()` as a sanity check. Have a careful read of https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php .....more specifically the `$x = 0;` and `$x = 1;` and note the difference.
It's simply a matter of providing an answer with the information I have provided to me.
As mentioned before, feel free to post another answer, but this discussion will not force me to edit mine.

Comment: `!empty($a) && isset($a)` versus `!empty($a)` will ALWAYS have the same result.  Give me an `$a` value that makes the conditions give a different boolean result.  I'll save you some time, it's not possible.  `!empty() && isset()` is an anti-pattern that should not exist in any code (similar to `switch(true)` blocks).  I am not here to war; I just want to prevent researchers learning an anti-pattern.  I would like to delete all of these comments once I have convinced you.

Comment: @mickmackusa - if we use it the way you just gave, you are absolutely right. I’m at least convinced :)

Answer (score 0):

Now I had time to look at the feedback/answer.

I checked the value with `var_dump()` and it showed `NULL`.

The problem was solved with a correction of the check which @mickmackusa mentioned:

```
<?php if ($this->item->params->get('itemExtraFields') && !empty($this->item->extra_fields)): ?>
```

Comment: Please accept an answer on this page by awarding the green tick. Please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/352329